# Color String in the Label

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsstring, uilabel

If I want to create some strings having format as these:

the string is the text property of a label.
some characters in this string have color different from other characters.
some characters are underlined and have a link, and when I hit the characters, and other views pop up.

Could somebody tell me how can I realize this effect?

Comment: Read up on `NSAttributeString` and `UILabel attributedText`.

Comment: Please use this link https://github.com/dblapps/DAAttributedStringUtils. In this example you will find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you support iOS < 6, better use 3rd party component e.g. [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). Else use `attributedText` property of `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *colors = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blueColor], @"Hyd", [UIColor brownColor], @"Bang", [UIColor orangeColor], @"Delhi", [UIColor yellowColor], @"Gujarat", nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
for (NSString *word in colors) {
    UIColor *color = [colors objectForKey:word];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:color forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    NSAttributedString *substring = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:word attributes:attributes];
    [attributeString appendAttributedString:substring];
}
```